# Run junits in parallel in two jvms with ant

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have huge amount of junits and running all of them takes long time. But CPU and memory utilization is only about 30%. I can't run junits in parallel threads in the same jvm because they are not thread-safe and it's impossible to fix them.
As far as I know junit ant task start separate jvm to run junits.
Is it possible to run a couple of jvms from ant for junits? I assume such solution can significantly reduce execution time.

Currently I run them with ant using such code:

```
<for param="bundle" keepgoing="true">
<path>
    <dirset dir="${testdir}/plugins">
        <depth max="0"/>
    </dirset>
</path>
<sequential>

    <echo message="Running tests in bundle @{bundle}"/>
    <junit outputtoformatters="no" printsummary="yes" failureproperty="test.failed" maxmemory="512m" fork="yes"  forkmode="once">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="tests.classpath" />
        </classpath>

        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${junit.result.dir}">
            <fileset dir="@{bundle}/src">
                <patternset refid="test.sources" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</sequential>
```

Comment: Does [this blog post](http://blog.code-cop.org/2009/09/parallel-junit.html) describe what you're after?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html

> The primary use case for  is to run external programs such
>   as an application server, and the JUnit or TestNG test suites at the
>   same time. Anyone trying to run large Ant task sequences in parallel,
>   such as javadoc and javac at the same time, is implicitly taking on
>   the task of identifying and fixing all concurrency bugs the tasks that
>   they run.

which has this example

```
<parallel>
  <wlrun ... >
  <sequential>
    <sleep seconds="30"/>
    <junit fork="true" forkmode="perTest" ... >
    <wlstop/>
  </sequential>
</parallel>
```

Edit: updated forkmode settings

Comment: The documentation says that parallelism is achieved using threads, right? Isn't this conflicting with the askers request?

Comment: Threads are used to start JUNIT Ant tasks, which in turn are configured to start separate JVM instances. That's what fork="true" is for.